# Get and set spacing between UIBarButtonItem items?

Tags: ios, swift

I added 2 UIBarButtonItems to a toolbar, and there is a lot of spacing between them. What property or methods do I use to read or adjust this, so I can make sure my objects dimensions depend on each device's width and use all of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto Layout Constraints to set space between these buttons. Here is the link
[AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutConcepts/AutoLayoutConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH14-SW1)

Comment: Yeah, I normally use that, but what would I set my `CGRectMake` dimensions to then? If I hard code dimensions, will the constraints override them?

Comment: While using constraints, you don't need to set the frame size. And constraints will do that for you.